# how do i set a timeout value for python's mechanize?

Tags: python, timeout, mechanize

How do i set a timeout value for python's mechanize?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Alex is correct: `mechanize.urlopen` takes a `timeout` argument. Therefore, just insert a number of [seconds in floating point](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout): `mechanize.urlopen('http://url/', timeout=30.0)`.

The background, from the source of `mechanize.urlopen`:

```
def urlopen(url, data=None, timeout=_sockettimeout._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT):
    ...
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
```

What is `mechanize._sockettimeout._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT` you ask? It's just the `socket` module's setting.

```
import socket

try:
    _GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
except AttributeError:
    _GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = object()
```

Comment: Good old `br.open()` looks to have a timeout parameter as well: https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/blob/b1d786906946f0193051920a7c716b339bd7bf95/mechanize/_mechanize.py#L200

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Python 2.6 or better, and a correspondingly updated version of `mechanize`, `mechanize.urlopen` should accept a `timeout=...` optional argument which seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I believe something along the lines of

```
mechanize._sockettimeout._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 100
```

will override the default value Mechanize uses.

Comment: What is the default one?

Comment: mechanize._sockettimeout._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT.__sizeof__()  this one is giving 16